# Is it possible to run gitlab as https/ssh through OS-Login IAP tunnels?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab

We have a gitlab server running on a GCP instance. Currently this instance has a mapped internet IP and a proper DNS name. Recently we have desired to remove this internet IP and force all access through authenticated tunnels.

For other instances in the GCP environment this isn't an issue, however the engineers like to work with the code directly on their local systems rather than having to connect into the environment.

We are currently using OS-Login to provide both the tunneled ssh sessions as well as identity-aware-proxy (IAP) tunnels for access.

However I cannot wrap my head around how to map tunnels and DNS names so that the remote engineers can continue to use gitlab from their local systems.

Is this possible?

If so, how should I configure the IAP tunnels and DNS name(s) to make this work?

Thank you for your time.

Edit/Clarification:

The bottom line to what I want to accomplish is to remove the internet IP from my gitlab server in the GCP environment without breaking any of the git repos that engineers currently have on their workstations or any of the currently existing tools/scripts inside the GCP environment.

So what I want is a set up such that an engineer can sit on his workstation at home and use a gitlab server in my GCP environment, using only OS-Logn and IAP-Tunnels to communicate with it.

This set-up would refer to the server as gitlab.mydomain.com, even though the IAP-tunnels are really ports on localhost, because systems in the GCP environment still have to use it without IAP tunnels.

And, just for fun, I have engineers on linux, windows *and* macintosh computers.

Comment: IAP does not use DNS names.

Comment: Can you explain in details what do you want to achieve here ? How do you want it to work ?

Comment: Review this document to set up TCP Forwarding: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding Note: I have not tested this with GitLab and this will break items such as SSL certificates. I think the better approach is to have a public IP address and then configure VPC Firewall Rules to only allow your IP addresses to access the server OR set up a VPN such as OpenVPN or WireGuard.

Answer (score 1):

Using TCP forwarding makes DNS protocol useless since it uses UDP (not TCP).

Also as [John Hanley mentioned](https://serverfault.com/questions/1061619/is-it-possible-to-run-gitlab-as-https-ssh-through-os-login-iap-tunnels#comment1383351_1061619) - this will break all SSL certificates.

> Note: I have not tested this with GitLab and this will break items such as SSL certificates. I think the better approach is to have a public IP address and then configure VPC Firewall Rules to only allow your IP addresses to access the server OR set up a VPN such as OpenVPN or WireGuard.

Additionally keep in mind the limitations when using TCP Forwarding:

> **Bandwidth:** IAP's TCP forwarding feature isn't intended for bulk transfer of data. IAP reserves the right to rate-limit users abusing this service.
>
> **Connection length:** IAP automatically disconnects sessions after 1 hour of inactivity. We recommend having logic in your applications to handle reestablishing a tunnel when it becomes disconnected.

The latter shouldn't be an issue since I don't think anyone would keep the tunnel inactive for so long while working.

I'd take John's advice about using VPN instead of a TCP forwarding into consideration. This will allow you run any software protocol without issues and bandwidth rate limiting.

You can also restrict access to the VM using GCP Firewall rules.